# Knockout js - Change return checkbox value null if condition true

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js

I am new with Knockout js, i have checkbox and return value with condition.

I want change return value null if condition true, but i dont know how:

```
isChecked: ko.computed(function () {
            return quote.paymentMethod() ? quote.paymentMethod().method : 'payu';
        }),

        isCheckedToShowTooltip: function () {
            $(".loading-mask").addClass("hide");

            if($(".payment-method").length == 0) {
                if ($(".multiple_payment_method").length == 0) {
                    $(".billing-address-list").before('<h4 class="multiple_payment_method"><span>Datos de envío</span></h4>');
                    $(".block.items-in-cart.active div.title").addClass("hide");
                    $(".block.items-in-cart").before('<h4 class="multiple_payment_method"><span>Resumen de tu compra</span></h4>');
                    $("#checkout-payment-method-load").before('<h4 class="multiple_payment_method"><span>Método de pago</span></h4>');
                }
                if ($(".multiple_payment_method").length == 3) {
                    this.isChecked() = null; //<----------------Here not work
                }
            }

            if(quote.paymentMethod()) {
                if($("#seccion-payu-below").length > 0) {
                    $("#seccion-payu-below").remove();
                }

                if($("#seccion-efecty-below").length > 0) {
                    $("#seccion-efecty-below").remove();
                }

                switch(quote.paymentMethod().method) {
                  case "payu":
                          $('#initial-payu-container').remove();
                          $('#checkout-payment-method-load').removeClass('container-initial');
                          $("#payment-methods-group-list" ).after("<div id='seccion-payu-below'>" + $("#seccion-payu").html() + "</div>");
                          $("#seccion-payu-below button").removeAttr("data-bind data-posicion data-origen");

                          if($("#seccion-payu button").hasClass("disabled")) {
                              $("#seccion-payu-below button").attr('disabled','disabled').addClass("disabled");
                          } else {
                              $("#seccion-payu-below button").removeAttr('disabled','disabled').removeClass("disabled");
                          }

                          $("#seccion-payu-below button").attr({ id: "button_payu_below", type: "button", onclick: "submitPaymentMethod('" + quote.paymentMethod().method + "');" });

                          if($('#payu').is(':checked')) {
                              $('#seccion-payu-below').show();
                          }
                    break;
                  case "efecty":
                          $('#initial-payu-container').remove();
                          $('#checkout-payment-method-load').removeClass('.container-initial');
                          $("#payment-methods-group-list" ).after("<div id='seccion-efecty-below'>" + $("#seccion-efecty").html() + "</div>");
                          $("#seccion-efecty-below button").removeAttr("data-bind data-posicion data-origen");

                          if($("#seccion-efecty button").hasClass("disabled")) {
                              $("#seccion-efecty-below button").attr('disabled','disabled').addClass("disabled");
                          } else {
                              $("#seccion-efecty-below button").removeAttr('disabled','disabled').removeClass("disabled");
                          }

                          $("#seccion-efecty-below button").attr({ id: "button_efecty_below", type: "button", onclick: "submitPaymentMethod('" + quote.paymentMethod().method + "');" });

                          if($('#efecty').is(':checked')) {
                              $('#seccion-efecty-below').show();
                          }
                    break;
                }
            }
        },
```

I tried mentioned condition and not work

And i know read and write properties but i do not know if this is my case

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `this.isChecked() = null;` does not make sense. You are calling a function called isChecked and setting it to null..... What exactly is that line supposed to be doing?

Comment: @epascarello I want to change value of isChecked after return value quote.paymentMethod().method or 'payu' to null if condition true, is it possible?

Comment: Does not make sense. Your computed should be using some other property which would be checked along with what you have. You should be setting that property. `this.paymentMethodValid && quote.paymentMethod() ......`

Comment: Thanks this works @epascarello i edit condition that i needed, i specify all in answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks epascarello i edit condition, and solve the problem, add new validation for that:

```
isChecked: ko.computed(function () {
            if (quote.paymentMethod()) {
                return quote.paymentMethod().method
            } else if (!rendererList._latestValue.some(item => item.type === 'efecty')) {
                return 'payu';
            } else {
                $('#checkout-payment-method-load').removeClass('container-initial');
                return null;
            }
        }),
```

Grettings!